# Spyder's Kite keeps inotify watches on all my home folder. Can I avoid it?

Tags: python, rstudio, spyder, inotify, kite

I recently upgraded Spyder to v4.0.0, which now suggests [Kite](https://kite.com/about/) for handling autocompletion. It works really fine but induces a system-wide error from `inotify`, wrongly entitled "No space left on device". Note that I first saw this error when starting RStudio, although it is not the culprit. The error [actually means](https://askubuntu.com/a/155426) that the maximum number of inotify watches has been reached. I was able to trace the error back to Kite by using [this great script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/502812/383047). And I noticed that Kite keeps a watch on every single file in my home folder!

My question is *not* about hacking a fix to the error: methods for increasing the number of available inotify watches have been discussed [elsewhere](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3267#issuecomment-410765981).

What I would like, instead, is a way to limit the folder(s) watched by Kite. Because every watch [consumes 1K](https://askubuntu.com/a/155426) of unswappable system memory and reserving ~500MB of RAM for monitoring my holiday pictures won't help for code completion.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This is not really the place to discuss about this problem. Instead, please open an issue [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) and post the results of the script you mentioned to see if it's really Kite or Spyder the ones that are consuming your inotify watches (Spyder also uses inotify internally to keep track of changes in your project files).

Comment: Actually I just found [this page](https://help.kite.com/article/85-linux-inotify-watches-limit) on Kite support web site. So this is the expected behavior of Kite, although annoying in my case. I contacted their support and will keep this thread updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it yet, but the issue should now be fixed. Thanks to the devs! See [this comment](https://github.com/kiteco/issue-tracker/issues/167#issuecomment-631607425)